# Twilio Conversation Disconnects for No Reason

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-conversations

I am using the Twilio Conversations JavaScript client and am running into issues with a conversation randomly disconnecting.

I am using react and am careful to look out for unnecessary rerenders but it's only with direct Conversation objects that I run into disconnects. The overall client works as expected.

Here is my example useEffect that holds the client itself

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!conversations.token) {
      return;
    }

    const conversationClient = new ConversationsClient(conversations.token, {
      retryWhenThrottledOverride: true,
    });

    conversationClient.on('connectionStateChanged', (state) => {
      // dispatch data to store
    });

    conversationClient.on('stateChanged', (state) => {
      // dispatch data to store
    });

    conversationClient.on('initialized', async () => {
      // dispatch data to store
    });

    conversationClient.on('initFailed', (error) => {
      // dispatch data to store
    });

    conversationClient.on('conversationAdded', (conversation) => {
      // dispatch data to storeispatch(addConversation(conversation));
      }
    });

    conversationClient.on('conversationLeft', (conversation) => {
      // dispatch data to store
    });

    conversationClient.on(
      'conversationUpdated',
      ({ conversation, updateReasons }) => {
        // dispatch data to store
      },
    );

    conversationClient.on('conversationRemoved', (conversation) => {
      // dispatch data to store
    });

    conversationClient.on('messageAdded', (message) => {
      // dispatch data to store
    });

    conversationClient.on('tokenAboutToExpire', async () => {
      // dispatch data to store
    });

    conversationClient.on('tokenExpired', async () => {
      // dispatch data to store
    });

    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      conversationClient.shutdown();
    };
  }, [conversations.token]);
```

Then when I try to access a conversation like the following

```js
const messageCursor = await conversation.getMessages();
```

However, at seemingly random times, I am met with the following error after a conversation becomes 'disconnected'.

```
Unable to connect: Connection is not initialized

Error: Unable to connect: Connection is not initialized
    at Upstream.send (browser.js?6941:3009:1)
    at _class._callee5$ (browser.js?6941:3816:1)
    at tryCatch (regeneratorRuntime.js?a677:44:1)
    at Generator.eval (regeneratorRuntime.js?a677:125:1)
    at Generator.eval [as next] (regeneratorRuntime.js?a677:69:1)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?d0db:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?d0db:22:1)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?d0db:27:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at _class.eval (asyncToGenerator.js?d0db:19:1)
    at _class.get (browser.js?6941:3830:1)
    at eval (browser.js?82ff:1212:1)
    at Retrier.eval (browser.js?82ff:1160:1)
    at emitOne (browser.js?bc71:121:1)
    at Retrier.emit (browser.js?bc71:207:1)
    at Retrier.attempt (browser.js?bc71:566:1)
    at eval (browser.js?bc71:625:1)
```

Is there a way to reconnect to the conversation or mitigation for disconnecting in the first place?